# Specify page_count parameter from API request

Tags: python, parameters, python-requests

I'm downloading json data from an API, but I am having trouble setting a parameter. Specifically, I'd like create the option of setting how many number of pages I'd like to download from the API. My code looks something like this:

```
# Libraries
import json, requests

# Define API, endpoint, and page number
url = 'https://api-v2.themuse.com/jobs?page=1'

# Set page count parameter
params = {'page_count': 10}

# Request data from API and store into object
resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)

# Save data as JSON
data = json.loads(resp.text)
```

However, the 'params' function doesn't set the number of pages I want to download: Instead of 10 pages, I download 100 pages. Any thoughts? If it helps, the JSON structure looks something like this:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "page_count": 100,
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 35210
}
```

Comment: are you sure you don't want a query param eg `https://api-v2.themuse.com/jobs?page=1&page_count=10`?

Comment: It looks like `page_count` isn't a valid parameter, I got 100 on my side as well.

Comment: @jordanm I just tried and it didn't work. Good suggestion, though!!

Comment: @Shane Yeah, I have no idea what to do. I suppose I could just download all of it and then section every chunk or so as a page, but that's so counter-intuitive.

Comment: Their API documentation says `page_count` is the number of total pages, not the number per page. It's not a param their API accepts as input.

Comment: Jordanm's response doesn't achieve anything. Using `params` in the requests call or manually constructing the URL does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [API specification](https://www.themuse.com/developers/api/v2), `page_count` is an output parameter and not something you specify. Response data is paginated with 20 results per page.

You are requesting `page=1` (the index starts from page 0) and getting back 20 results. To get all the data for the first 10 pages, do something like this:

```
jobs_url = 'https://api-v2.themuse.com/jobs'

for i in range(11):
    results_data = json.loads(requests.get(
        url=jobs_url,
        params={'page': i}
    ).text)['results']

    #do something with the data
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: How would you turn this nested JSON into a pandas dataframe?
I've considered using `json_normalize` but not sure if it's the best idea.